# How to prevent Google Maps SVG markers from clobbering each other

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I dynamically place SVG markers onto a Google Map.  If 2 svg markers happen to be in the same location they clobber each other like below (1).  If they are even a bit spaced out, they look fine (2):

[image]

The example is in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/RobertGelb/pen/yKpBmo).  Other than manually moving the marker a bit or not displaying it, what can I do to fix this issue?  For brevity, here is how I build a marker:

```
var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pointA,      
  label: {
    text: "A",
    color: "white"
  },
  icon: {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
      encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="rgb(78, 144, 217)" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" /></svg>'),
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
  },
  optimized: false,
  map: map
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem occurs when the computed `zIndex` for the markers are the same.

Looks like a bug in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

A workaround would be to set the `zIndex` yourself, set the `zIndex` of the marker that should appear on top to a more positive value.

(note that if you are going to set the zIndex yourself, you have to do it for **all** the markers for it to work correctly)

```
var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pointB,  
  zIndex: 10,
  label: {
    text: "A",
    color: "white"
  },
  icon: {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
      encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="rgb(78, 144, 217)" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" /></svg>'),
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
  },
  map: map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uv5d2tcd/)

[image: screenshot of map with markers on top of each other]

[image: screenshot of map with markers slightly offset]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3163803, -6.2676661),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(53.316388, -6.2676661),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      zIndex: 0,
      draggable: true,
      title: "SVG icon",
      label: {
        text: "10",
        color: "white"
      },
      icon: {
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="#4E90D9" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="10" /></svg>',
        size: new google.maps.Size(200, 200),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
      },
      map: map
    });
  var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointB,
    zIndex: 10,
    draggable: true,
    label: {
      text: "A",
      color: "white"
    },
    icon: {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
        encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="rgb(78, 144, 217)" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" /></svg>'),
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) third-party library for the Javascript API. It expands close together points similar to how Google Earth does with its pushpins.

Here's a [simple JSBin proof of concept](http://jsbin.com/vikovovima/edit?html,output) adapted from your original code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cluster</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
       html, body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.3/oms.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
    <script>
     function initMap() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3163803, -6.2676661);
  var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3163803, -6.2676661);

  // uncomment below to move the marker a bit and make the clobbering go away
  // var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3164803, -6.2676661);

  var  myOptions = { zoom: 15, center: pointB };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

  var url ='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
        encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="rgb(78, 144, 217)" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" /></svg>');

  var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointA,
    label: {
      text: "A",
      color: "white"
    },
    icon: {
      url: url,
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    optimized: false
  });

  var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointB,
    label: {
      text: "B",
      color: "white"
    },
    icon: {
      url: url,
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    optimized: false
  });

  //Save the marker labels as separate fields, so that their labels can be changed with OMS
  markerA.id = 'A';
  markerB.id = 'B';

  //Declare the Spiderfier and add the markers
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
  oms.addMarker(markerA);
  oms.addMarker(markerB);

  //Check for the 'format' event and update the marker label
  oms.addListener('format', function(marker, status) {
      var label;
        switch (status) {
          //'SPIDERFIABLE' means the markers are clustered up; show a '+' sign to denote they can be
          //expanded
          case OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE:
            label = '+';
            break;
          //'SPIDERFIED' means the markers are expanded; restore the original label from the id field
          case OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED:
            label = marker.id;
            break;
        };
        marker.setLabel({text:label, color: "white"});
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```